Trouble connecting Modem in Ubuntu
How can I connect a modem to Ubuntu? I have tried multiple times, but it hasn't worked. Do I need any additional software or drivers? The system detects the modem, but when I click on it, it just shows "connecting..."

Try something like 'minicom' or 'putty', both are terminal-emulators that lets you configure the modem connection as a serial line. What are you connecting to in 'the other end' ?

What is the version of Ubuntu?

What modem is it? Brand and model.

Modem Types
Make sure this Modem is not a WinModem which uses the CPU to convert digital signals into analog signals while a Classic Modem uses a special chip inside the modem for this function.
Required:
The phone number of your Internet provider (ISP)
The username and password used to connect to your ISP
The IP node of your ISP's DNS server
It is necessary that ppp and chat be installed, if they are not installed, you must install the chat and ppp DEBs.
The installation of a real Modem must be automatic, by executing the command:
sudo dmesg
All the "Hardware" detected at startup is displayed, there you can analyze if the Modem was detected.
To establish an Internet connection via dial-up, the pppd daemon must be invoked, which pppd requires several parameters, using some tools such as Chat to automate the dialing process, which uses a script that contains all the parameters necessary to make a dial-up connection. -up:
ABORT 'BUSY'
ABORT 'NO CARRIER'
''ATZ
OK ATDT11-1111111
CONNECT ''
This script should be located in the /etc/ppp/ directory with a friendly name like: scriptchat with permissions 755
The '' characters indicate that no response should be expected from the modem, therefore the ATZ command should be sent immediately to the modem.
When the OK signal is received from the "Modem", the signal ATDT11-1111111 must be sent, this last signal contains the number that will be dialed by the modem (11-1111111).
When the CONNECT signal is received from the Modem, no action is necessary ('').
The ATs defined in the script are generally valid for all Modem vendors.
ATDP dials the phone expecting pulse service.
ATDT is widely used in tone service.
If it is necessary to wait a period of time, the "," which allows you to wait a period of time before continuing to dial, ATDT1,,,11-1111111 indicates that you must dial 1 and wait 3 seconds before dialing 11-1111111, like when you have a corporate telephone network.
Within the /etc/ppp directory there must be the pap-secrets file
This file must contain the username and password that were assigned by your ISP, follow the format indicated in the file.
Once the chat script has been written and the users and passwords have been defined in pap-secrets, it is necessary to configure some parameters that pppd will use
To invoke pppd, another script similar to the one used by chat is generally defined under the /etc/ppp/peers/ directory.
This script makes it easy to run pppd.
The content of a pppd script is as follows:
ttyS1 38400 lock crtscts noipdefault
user rabiul
defaultroute 0.0.0.0:0.0.0.0
connect '/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/ppp/scriptchat'
The first parameter is the "device" on which the modem is located, typically it is ttyS1 (Serial Port 2), the sudo dmesg command verifies its location.
The second parameter indicates the speed that the modem will use in bps, lock allows the modem not to be manipulated by any other system process, while crtscts means that Hardware "flow control" will be used, noipdefault indicates that the IP address cannot be obtained from the "Host" that is initiating the dialing, therefore it must be obtained from the ISP.
The user rabiul line indicates the user who will make the connection, defined in pap-secrets.
defaultroute indicates that a "default" route must be added to the system's routing table to ensure that all unknown information packets are sent to this interface, 0.0.0.0:0.0.0.0 means the IP address of the local "Host" and the Remote "Host" IP address (ISP) respectively, 0.0.0.0 indicates that these addresses will be assigned by the remote "Host".
And finally connect '/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/ppp/scriptchat' runs the script for chat.
Up to this point in the configuration it is only possible to establish a Dial-up connection with our ISP, to find names on the Internet, it is necessary to modify the /etc/resolv.conf file that contains at least the following parameters:
nameserver 203.23.12.1
nameserver 203.23.12.2
Where 203.23.12.1 and 203.23.12.2 are the IP nodes of your ISP's DNS servers.
Two other files also located within the /etc/ppp directory are used when starting and ending the Dial-up connection. In the case of ip-up, this script is executed every time a Dial-up connection is started, while ip- down is executed every time a dial-up connection is terminated.
To terminate the Dial-up connection it is convenient to define a script that performs the termination, place it inside /etc/ppp so that it is accessible from any directory, executing the following script would terminate the connection:
#!/bin/sh
killall 'pppd'
Gnome PPP is a connection manager that is ideal for configuring various servers.
